# How to apply a scipy median filter to a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, accelerometer

i'm working on a project with raw accelerometer data. I have read in a bunch of csv files into a Pandas dataframe with labels x,y,z,subject_id. Because the data is noisy i want to apply a median filter but somehow that doesn't work for me. Does anybody know how to do that?

This is how it looks for now:

```
from scipy import signal


subjects_df=signal.medfilt(subjects_df,kernel_size=3)
```

Thank's in advance.
Guido

Answer (score 0):

I would try this way.

```
subjests_df.apply(signal.medfilt, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

```
subjests_df.apply(lambda x: signal.medfilt(x, kernel_size=3))
```